# Регулярные выражения (Regex) для обработки сразу нескольких строк

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

День добрый. Столкнулся тут со следующей проблемой.
Обрабатываю большие массивы текста для вычленения массива только ключевых значений и все отлично, пока дело не касается нескольких строк.

Для примера, мне надо удалить все между ключами 1 и 2

```
Ключ1">текст

который 

надо убрать.<

Ключ2
```

Чтобы получить в итоге файл со строками, те убрать текст между ограничителями ">  < и сами ограничители. Пример, что хочу получить

```
Ключ1

Ключ2
```

Не подскажете, каким регулярным выражением это сделать?

Comment: прочитайте, пожалуйста, описание использованной вами метки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: Задача ничем не отличается от точно такой же в пределах одной строки. В начале регулярного выражения указать Ключ1, в конце указать Ключ2. Между ними любое количество любых симоволов, включая перевод строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> убрать текст между ограничителями "> < и сами ограничители

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
let s = `Ключ1">текст

который

надо убрать.<

Ключ2`
const r = /">[^<]*</g
s = s.replace(r, '')
console.log(s)
```

Comment: Моя вина. Не указал, что регулярные выражения выполняю в Notepad++ путем поиска и замены. Но извлеченный из ответа код ">[^<]*< отлично сработал, так что большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас текст, который нужно удалить ограничен определёнными символами, то можно (а скорее всего - нужно) обойтись без использования регулярных выражений:

```js
let str = `Ключ1>текст

который

надо убрать.<

Ключ2> ещё тексе
который
тоже нужно удалить.<

Ключ3`,
newStr = '',
isIgnored = false;

for( let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  let c = str.charAt(i);
  if(c == '>') {
    isIgnored = true;
  } else if(c == '<') {
    isIgnored = false;
  } else if(!isIgnored) {
    newStr += c;
  }
}
console.log("newStr: " + newStr);
```

Comment: Если реализовывать такую "нужду" - быстрее будет использовать `.indexOf()`, а не бежать по символьно. ;)

Comment: @ksa ну или так... Оба варианта будут быстрее регулярок. В любом случае это не подходит для NPP... Автор прокомментировал предыдущий ответ с  уточнением, пока я писал ответ...